# QT, QPointer from parent to child

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I have a more complex use-case where I investigate a crash and it boils down to a QParent holding a QChild object by QPointer (QParent creates QChild by passing "this" as a parent as bellow)

```
m_child = new QChild(this)
```

In this program there is also a strange backwards relationship from QChild to QParent:

```
QChild(QParent* parent): QObject(parent), m_parent(parent)

where m_parent is QPointer<QParent>
```

Basically here  QChild is parented by the "QParent* parent" pointer and also holds a QPointer through m_parent.

1. Why would anyone create QChild() and parenting it with QParent in QChild constructor while also holding an additional QPointer member to QParent inside QChild (instead of a raw pointer to QParent)
2. When QParent gets deleted it calls as part of it's QObject base class destructor deletion of QChild, but QChild also has a QPointer member to QParent. I have the impression that this can call back into already destructed QParent through QPointer m_parent member.
3. There is a hard to reproduce crash(cannot reproduce this normally) that points to QParent->QChild destruction (QChild destroyed inside QParent destructor). If 2 is true (calling of QParent destructor from inside QChild) than it is possible though.

Comment: The documentation for [QPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) says this: ***A guarded pointer, QPointer<T>, behaves like a normal C++ pointer T *, except that it is automatically cleared when the referenced object is destroyed (unlike normal C++ pointers, which become "dangling pointers" in such cases).***

Comment: You are right. There should be no issues regarding calling back into the parent from the child Object. When the QChild is destroyed though, in the QObject base class destructor something happens though that causes seg fault. I need to understand many things done in that QT class (connections etc). QChild has signals received from QParent. I wonder if QParent has some pending signals for QChild would that be handled properly in this case (as part of the QParent destruction) ?

Comment: The signals should automatically be disconnected when the child is freed. However there are warnings about events and threads: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

Comment: Wanted to say that QChild also can send signals back to QParent. If it does that as part of QChild destructor then it calls into deleted QParent instance (at least the derived from QObject part of QParent is destroyed at this point).